# Can I use a mechanical pipette to transfer strong acid?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, equipment

I am an undergraduate student majoring in physics. I am looking for the best method to accurately measure the volume of strong acids like hydrobromic $(w(\ce{HBr(aq)}) = 48\,\%)$ and hydroiodic $(w(\ce{HI(aq)}) = 57\,\%)$ acids. I need milliliter volumes, and since I'm going to pour or dispense a specific volume of acid in a vial, I mean "to deliver". The only measuring device I could think of is a mechanical pipette, but I am afraid the acids or their corrosive vapors could damage the pipette's mechanism.

I don't have any friends or colleagues majored in chemistry, so I am having a hard time trying to decide which pipette to buy. I really have no clues on how actual chemists who use strong acids accurately measure them, so I'll be pleased with any kind of help.

Comment: Concentrated acids are seldom measured precisely, as their concentration is not precise either.

Comment: I think there are Hamilton syringes with glass/PTFE inserts/fittings which could resist these strong acids. But it's probably preferable to just weigh the acids instead if you can.

Comment: Maybe your advisor has friends who are chemists. It would be nice to have access to a chemist for considerations of [safety](https://www.fishersci.com/store/msds?partNumber=AC223325000&productDescription=HYDROBROMIC+ACID%2C+P.A.+500ML&vendorId=VN00032119&countryCode=US&language=en) and hazardous waste treatment.

Comment: Metallic pieces should be avoided, because they react with acids. But glass pipettes and rubber bulbs are resistant to strong acids like $\ce{HCl, HBr, HI}$ in solution or in a gaseous state.

Comment: PE/PP Hamilton syringe inserts should work too, unless it is for perchloric acid.

Comment: What accuracy is this supposed to have? How often do you need to do it?

Comment: If you want good, well reproducible accuracy, this there https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCrette#/media/Datei:Buerette2.jpg might be what you're going to need. Be prepared for a bill in the region of 1k for three of them. And you still need to calibrate the titre factor every few days.

Comment: Of course you can also dilute the acid, which will increase accuracy in pipetting or allow use of graduated cylinders.

Comment: Another possible solution is [positive displacement pipettes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_displacement_pipette), though I don't know much about them